c7n-mailer is not sending message to slack channel
Sends email just fine but not slack messages.  Any ideas?  Nothing in cloudwatch logs.
- name: ec2-tag-compliance-mark
  resource: ec2
  comment: |
    Find all (non-ASG) instances that are not conformant to tagging policies, and tag them for stoppage in 1 hour.
  filters:
    - "tag:aws:autoscaling:groupName": absent
    - "tag:c7n_status": absent
    - or:
        - "tag:Owner": absent
        - "tag:Project": absent
  actions:
    - type: mark-for-op
      tag: c7n_status
      op: stop
      hours: 1
    - type: notify
      slack_template: slack_default
      slack_msg_color: danger
      violation_desc: Find all (non-ASG) instances that are not conformant to tagging policies, and tag them for stoppage in 1 hour.
      action_desc: Please go TAG your resources with "Owner" and "Project".
      to:
        - https://hooks.slack.com/services/T01QS1D2SET/B07HUKEG97W/XXXXX
        - albert@onehouse.ai
      transport:
        type: sqs
        queue: https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/654654235321/cloudcustodian

